# Truncating an md5 hash, How do I calculate the odds of a collision occurring?

Tags: md5

I want to truncate an md5 hash to about half size. How much does that increase the odds of collisions? if I'm dealing with around 500 000 generations, should I be worried about a collision? what about 1m generations.

Comment: Just to be clear about the question, are you saying that you want to start with a weak hash algorithm that already has known vulnerabilities, then intentionally make it even weaker?

Comment: he's not necessarily using a hash for security

Answer (score 18):

The math you're looking for is on Wikipedia's [birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) page.

> We consider the following experiment. From a set of *H* values we choose *n* values uniformly at random thereby allowing repetitions. Let *p(n; H)* be the probability that during this experiment at least one value is chosen more than once. This probability can be approximated as
>
> [image: p(n;H) ~= 1-e^(-n^2/(2H))]

With 128 bits the chance of a collision among 500,000 hash values is around [10<sup>-28</sup>](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-e%5E%28-500000%5E2/%282%2A2%5E128%29%29). If you halve the size of the collision space then the chance of collision is around [10<sup>-9</sup>](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-e%5E%28-500000%5E2/%282%2A2%5E64%29%29). That is, even though the chance is *vastly* greater it's still very, very low. It depends on how critical it is that there be no collisions. 10<sup>-9</sup> is on the order of one in a billion, so while extremely unlikely it's within the realm of possibility.

For reference:

10<sup>28</sup> = 10 octillion = 10 billion billion billion
10<sup>9</sup> = 1 billion

Comment: someone once said "once in a million is next tuesday" :)

Comment: 10^-9 would seriously worry me. MD5 in general has a worrisome number of collisions not to mention all the rainbow tables around these days.

Answer (score 2):

There's an interesting mathematical problem called the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table) that deals with that kind of situation. The fact is that the more entries you push in, the higher the chances to have a collision.

Following the table posted on the above link, assuming your digests are 64 bits each (since a single MD5 hash is 128 bits) and that MD5 have a uniform distribution, there is a very low chance that two hashes will collide. It becomes significant (1% chance or more) at 610,000,000 entries.