# Splitting a sha256 hash

Tags: php, sha256

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it okay to truncate a SHA256 hash to 128 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026762/is-it-okay-to-truncate-a-sha256-hash-to-128-bits)

Can anyone tell me to what degree entropy would be affected if only the first 35 characters of a sha256 hash were to be returned?  What is the risk in doing this?

Comment: It was in a script I downloaded.  I figure since the original/intended length was 64 characters, returning only the first 35 must be detrimental in some way. My question is: how?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on what the hash is being used for.

Comment: session hash. tells whether the user is logged in or not and gets their username/rights from a session table with the hash

Comment: You should edit your question to include the extra information. Also it would be good to say what data is being hashed, since the output space of a hash function can't be larger than the input space.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure what exactly you are asking for.
Your 35 chars represent 17.5 bytes that are 140bits

```
256 bit: 2^256 = 1.1E+77
140 bit: 2^140 = 1,4E+42
```

So entropy is dramatically reduced. Hope this helps.